# Cisco ASA 8.2 ACL For NAT

Tags: nat, cisco-asa, access-control-list

Sadly I have gone back in time to ASA 8.2(5)33 which I am not so familiar with. I have configured NAT between two interfaces but traffic isn't passing becasue I can't get the ACL to work;

(The full config which isn't very big is [here](http://paste2.org/p/2530571) but to keep this post tidy I have just pasted the important parts below);

```
interface Ethernet0/0
 switchport access vlan 108
!
interface Ethernet0/6
 switchport access vlan 104
!             
interface Ethernet0/7
 switchport access vlan 105
!             
interface Vlan104
 description BUILDING2
 nameif BUILDING2
 security-level 0
 ip address 10.104.0.1 255.255.255.0 
!             
interface Vlan105
 description BUILDING1
 nameif BUILDING1
 security-level 0
 ip address 10.105.0.1 255.255.255.0 
!             
interface Vlan108
 description Main LAN VLAN
 nameif lan   
 security-level 0
 ip address 172.22.0.215 255.255.255.0 
!
object-group network obj_net_Remote_Hosts
 network-object host 111.111.111.3
 network-object host 111.111.111.65
object-group network obj_host_pc1_eth1
 network-object host 10.104.0.111
object-group network obj_host_pc2_eth1
 network-object host 10.104.0.112
object-group network obj_host_pc3_eth1
 network-object host 10.104.0.106
object-group network obj_host_pc4_eth1
 network-object host 10.104.0.107
object-group network obj_net_PCs
 description IPs of PCs
 group-object obj_host_pc1_eth1
 group-object obj_host_pc2_eth1
 group-object obj_host_pc3_eth1
 group-object obj_host_pc4_eth1
access-list acl_NAT_pc1_91 extended permit tcp host 10.104.0.111 host 111.111.111.3 eq 8101 
access-list acl_Permit_PCs extended permit tcp object-group obj_net_PCs object-group obj_net_Remote_Hosts eq 8101 
!
global (BUILDING1) 11 111.111.222.91 netmask 255.255.255.255
nat (BUILDING2) 11 access-list acl_NAT_pc1_91
access-group acl_Permit_PCs in interface BUILDING2
route BUILDING1 111.111.111.3 255.255.255.255 10.105.0.2 1
route BUILDING1 111.111.111.65 255.255.255.255 10.105.0.2 1
```

When I try and connect from PC1 to ip 111.111.111.3 I see the following error logged on the ASA console;

```
%ASA-2-106001: Inbound TCP connection denied from 10.104.0.111/38495 to 111.111.111.3/8101 flags SYN  on interface blades
```

What the duce!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enable [same-security-traffic](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/security/asa/asa82/command/reference/s1.html#wp1421315).

```
same-security-traffic enable inter-interface
```

Or change one of the interfaces security level

Comment: Oh man, that seems obvious now, either way I needed anothers opinion, thank you :)